# The '<' character gets displayed while I'm typing <br>

Tags: javascript

I need to add a line break, so I used a `<br>` tag. However, that causes a left bracket (`<`) to display for some milliseconds before actually applying the line break.

Here's my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <div id="typing" class="typing"></div>

  <script>
    var typeString = ['I m Mr. Frits and <br> i love Pakistan...:)'];
        
    var  i = 0;
    var count = 0
    var selectedText = '';
    var text = '';

    (function type() {
      if (count == typeString.length) {
        count = 0;
      }
      selectedText = typeString[count];
      text = selectedText.slice(0, ++i);
      document.getElementById('typing').innerHTML = text.fontsize(50);
      document.getElementById('typing').style.fontFamily = "monospace";
      document.getElementById("typing").style.color = "black";
      document.getElementById("typing").style.fontWeight = "bold";
      
      if (text.length === selectedText.length) {
        count++;
        i = 0;
        
      }
      setTimeout(type, 300);
    }());

    function sleep(milliseconds) {
      var start = new Date().getTime();
      for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
        if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds) {
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can replace the `div` with a `pre`, then change the `<br>` with `\n`.

Or you can check for the tag and writ it at once.

Comment: Working with pre tag, thanks. What's the alternate of <b> tag for making single or couple of specific characters bold? Facing same problem with bold tag.

Answer (score 0):

As said by @Bahaa, here is a snippet of a working code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <pre id="typing" class="typing"></pre>
    <script>
    var typeString = ['I m Mr. Frits and\ni love Pakistan...:)'];
          var  i = 0;
          var count = 0
          var selectedText = '';
          var text = '';
          (function type() {
            if (count == typeString.length) {
              count = 0;
            }
            selectedText = typeString[count];
            text = selectedText.slice(0, ++i);
            document.getElementById('typing').innerHTML = text.fontsize(50);
            document.getElementById('typing').style.fontFamily = "monospace";
            document.getElementById("typing").style.color = "black";
            document.getElementById("typing").style.fontWeight = "bold";
            if (text.length === selectedText.length) {
              count++;
              i = 0;
            }
            setTimeout(type, 300);
          }());
    </script>
    </body>
    </html
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a good idea to put the formatting bits into a separate style section (CSS). This will keep your JavaScript shorter. I made a few changes, like putting all the variable declarations into the IIFE and replacing repeated `setTiemout()` calls by a single `setInterval()` call. Here is a working snippet

```js
var typeString = ['I \'m Mr. Frits and\nI love Pakistan...:)',
                  'It is\nso nice\nto meet\nyou!'];

(function(){
 var i=0,count=0;
 function type() {
  var selectedText,text;
  selectedText = typeString[count=count%typeString.length];
  text = selectedText.slice(0,++i);
  document.getElementById('typing').innerHTML = text;
  if (0==(i=i%selectedText.length)) ++count;
 }
 setInterval(type, 300);
})();
```

```css
#typing {font-family:monospace; font-size:30px; font-weight:900;
         white-space:pre-wrap}
```

```html
<div id="typing"></div>
```

Comment: Will try, thnaks